# How to get top(n) from kendo AutoComplete client side when filtering

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-autocomplete

I have the below autocomplete set to static `dataSource`

```
$("#search").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: AutoCompletedataTextField,
    filter: "startswith",
    ignoreCase: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    dataSource: tempArray,           
});
```

I need to get only top 10 items to be displayed in the control.
how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting the page size inside the dataSourceBlock

```
 dataSource: {
    data: tempArray,
    pageSize: 10
}
```